# 1st order ODE using Gronwall's Lemma

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi can someone explain how to do this question to me?

Let $f : (−1,∞) × R^2 → R^2$ be given by

$$f(t,x_1,x_2) = (\frac{1}{t + 1}(x_2 − x_1), −\frac{1}{t + 1}x_2)$$

and consider the ODE

$$x'(t) = f(t,x(t)).$$

Show that for a solution x(t) of the above differential equation we have

$$||x(t)|| ≤ \frac{1}{\sqrt{t + 1}}||x(0)||$$

Hint: Use Gronwall’s lemma 
and the fact that 
$$ab ≤\frac{1}{2}(a^2 + b^2), ∀ a, b ∈ R.$$

Additional details:
This is a question from my lecture notes to which the lecturer helpfully put the answer was obvious rather than any details.

My thoughts/ problem:
I understand (or at least think I do) this basis of this question i.e. Gronwall's Lemma.

For 
$$x'(t)≤a(t)x(t)  ∀ t∈(t0,t1)$$
Then
$$x(t)≤x(t_0)exp(\int_{t_0}^t a(s) ds)  ∀ t∈[t0,t1]$$

I can apply the lemma in given question most of the time. This time however I am struggling to find $a(t)$ and $x(t)$ for condition. This confusion comes mostly from the presence of $x_1$ and $x_2$ as I am unsure how to find $x(t)$ from them. As an educated guess I think that 
$$x'(t)=\frac{1}{t + 1}(x_2-x_1,-x_2)$$
$$a(t)=\frac{1}{t + 1}$$
$$x(t)=(x_2-x_1,-x_2)$$ 
$$t_0=-1$$

From that and Gronwall's Lemma I get

$$x(t)≤x(t_0)exp(-\int_{t_0}^t \frac{1}{s+1} ds)$$

$$(x_2-x_1,-x_2)≤x(-1)exp(-\int_{-1}^t \frac{1}{s+1} ds)$$

$$(x_2-x_1,-x_2)≤x(-1)exp(-ln(t+1)+ln(0))$$

$$(x_2-x_1,-x_2)≤x(-1)\frac{1}{t+1}$$

$$||(x_2-x_1,-x_2)||≤||x(-1)\frac{1}{t+1}||$$

$$||(x_2-x_1,-x_2)||≤||x(-1)||||\frac{1}{t+1}||$$

$$\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(-x_2)^2}≤||x(-1)||||\frac{1}{t+1}||$$

$$\sqrt{x_2^2-2x_2x_1+x_1^2+x_2^2}≤||x(-1)||||\frac{1}{t+1}||$$

$$2x_2^2-2x_2x_1+x_1^2≤||x(-1)||^2||\frac{1}{t+1}||^2$$

$$2x_2^2-2x_2x_1+x_1^2≤x(-1)^2(\frac{1}{t+1})^2$$

This as far as I can get and am fairly certain that it completely wrong may guess is that $x(t)=(x_2-x_1,-x_2)$ is wrong but honestly I have no idea.

p.s. sorry for the abysmal original post hope this more up to your standards.

Comment: Looks like you have plenty of help in the question. Look at the Related posts on the right hand side too.

Comment: Indeed redefining $x(t)=(x_2(t)-x_1(t),-x_2(t))$ although $x(t)$ is already defined as $x(t)=(x_1(t),x_2(t))$ is a sure way to produce chaos.

Comment: You are trying to use an inequality with a 2D vector in the first 4 lines above, which doesn't make much sense. Instead, consider $\| {x(t)} \|=( x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and compute its derivative using the chain rule. Use the inequality hint with ab to deal with the $x_1x_2$ term generated and you will have a first order DE for $\| {x(t)} \|$ with an $a(t)$ etc.

Comment: @Paul Thank you for reply I tried differentiating the norm and got $\frac{x_1+x_2}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^(1/2)}$ I can't see where to use inequality hint and no idea where to go from there. Any advice would appreciated.

Comment: @Widdows That is not the correct derivative of the norm. You will get derivatives multiplying $x_1$ and $x_2$ on the top line too. Note that the bottom line of the fraction is the norm too. Now substitute in the definition given of the derivatives of $x_1$ and $x_2$ from the ode. You will get an $x_1 x_2$ term which you can use the inequality hint on to end up with a multiple (your $a(t)$) of the norm. Apply Gronwall's from there.

Comment: @Paul How do you get a derivative that has $x_1$ and $x_2$ multiplied together? I did it via chain rule like you recommended and keep getting the same answer. $$g(x)=(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$  $$u=x_1^2+x_2^2  \frac{du}{dx}=2x_1+2x_2$$  $$v=u^{\frac{1}{2}}  \frac{dv}{du}=\frac{1}{2}u^{\frac{-1}{2}}$$ $$g'(x)=\frac{2(x_1+x_2)}{2(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$ $$g'(x)=\frac{x_1+x_2}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$Thank you once again.